# Squid3 to replace .jpg

Tags: debian, squid

I'm running `squid3-3.4.8`
i've been searching for a solution to replace cached jpg with other jpg stored on server or on internet. There are many tools like `squidred`, `volta`, `asqredir`. But none of them are working on Debian, or their guides are incomplete. I just need simple jpg link to replace with other link. Is there a way to do this?

I don't remember where i stuck on installing Volta for the first time. This time:

```
root@S:~/Volta/volta-0.3.0# make
Package lua5.2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `lua5.2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'lua5.2' found
cc -O2 -L/usr/lib -I/usr/include    -c -o accept_loop.o accept_loop.c
In file included from accept_loop.c:31:0:
volta.h:77:17: fatal error: lua.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [accept_loop.o] Error 1
```

I have donwloaded and installed Lua into `/root/Lua/lua-5.3.3`

Then tried `asqredir` from **guide** `asqredir.sourceforge.net`, but the section "testing asqredir" doesn't work.

For example when I type line to test:

```
www.samopage.com IP_of_computer - GET
```

I get an empty line. In browser also do not see jpg change.
Is there easy way to do this?

EDIT:

I tried changing `cache_effective_user` in `squid.conf` to root or proxy - do not work. Here is the logs from `cache.log`:

```
root@SRSQUID4:/var/log/squid3# cat /var/log/squid3/cache.log | tail
2016/06/11 19:46:54 kid1| ipcCreate: /root/asqredir/asqredir-0.3/asqredir: (13) Permission denied
2016/06/11 19:46:54 kid1| WARNING: redirector #Hlpr0 exited
2016/06/11 19:46:54 kid1| Too few redirector processes are running (need 1/5)
2016/06/11 19:46:54 kid1| Starting new helpers
2016/06/11 19:46:54 kid1| helperOpenServers: Starting 1/5 'asqredir' processes
```

asqredir rights:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11120 Jun  9 17:30 asqredir
```

EDIT:

after all i see white area instead of new photo. No matter if i choose redirected url: `https://www.dropbox.com/s/nf72mxln42n5dmr/testas2.jpg?raw=1` or `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/etP0OuZr71XL8GGv2lDWayip783yw1qV2KneRRRZK7HhX1NIE9sq4MQHjvPCeMEt/file` which is the result of first one.

Comment: Which guide have you been following, that doesn't work on Debian?

Comment: try installing `squidguard`.  It's packaged for debian.  You can use sets of common filters (e.g. to block porn) or use your own filter lists. or both.  http://www.squidguard.org/

Comment: debian also a `jesred` package, another redirector.  http://www.linofee.org/~elkner/webtools/jesred/

Comment: My answer amended to respond to your "permission denied" issue

Comment: in jesred i do not see the possibility to match against URL of picture in this situation

Answer (score 0):

For Volta, it looks like you need to `apt-get install liblua5.2-dev`

For `asqredir` it seems you've missed the section of the HOWTO guide that tells you to [uncomment and adapt the URL configuration file](http://asqredir.sourceforge.net/#edit). It's currently doing exactly what you've asked, which is to object to nothing.

Your testing matches exactly the test suggestion in that same HOWTO guide:

> now type a http request like squid would pass it for a non-blocked site:
>
> ```
> http://www.slashdot.org 192.168.25.132 - GET
> ```
>
> the output should be an empty new line

---

Following up with your (new) "permission denied" issue, the chances here are simply that the `squid` process doesn't have permission to access the script. As an example, typically `/root` has permissions `700` (`u=rwx,go=`). Move the script to somewhere that `squid` can access, such as `/usr/local/bin` and try it again.